# Magento doesnt save all data in table

Tags: sql, magento

I have an observer on  event. Oberver's code:

```
public function saveQuoteAfter($evt) {
        $quote = $evt->getQuote();
        $quoteIddd = $quote->getId();
        $email = $quote->getPEmail();
        $phone = $quote->getPPhone();
        $p = $quote->getPP();
        $fields = array('quote_id' => $quoteIddd, 'email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone, 'p' => $p);
        $model = Mage::getModel('my_module/quote')->setData($fields);
        $model->save(); 
    }
```

Mage::getModel('my_module/quote') - this is custom model that saves data to  table.
All variables exists and can be saved in first 3 columns in table. Cant save any data to any other further column.

```
install script:
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('module_quote')} (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `quote_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `phone` text NOT NULL,
  `p` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
$installer->endSetup();
```

So i cant save data to 'p' column. Any ideas why magento doesnt save data to these columns?

Answer (score -1):

ciemin instead of using  `of setData() use addData()`.

Because setData only save one column value
actully this function look like

```
 public function addData(array $arr)
    {
        foreach($arr as $index=>$value) {
            $this->setData($index, $value);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

**As using addData function you  can array value  with index but setData only save one value with index ex:setData('fieldname',$val)**

Comment: Actually setData, although able to set single object properties, is intended mainly for arrays of data (you can check how the method looks like in the Varien_Object class).

Comment: Your answer contains information that's wrong, Amit. The setData method can set more than one property at once.

Comment: actually setData() works too today. might be some cache issue?